# Grails: log4j logging always returns locationInfo inside SLF4JLog class

Tags: java, grails, log4j, slf4j

I have configured log4j in Config.groovy in this way:

```
log4j {
    appenders {
         console name:'stdout', 
             layout: pattern(conversionPattern: '%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %C.%M(%L): %m%n'),
             locationInfo: true
    }
}
```

Controllers and services call obvious `log.trace('message')` and log apears in console as well. **But always with wrong location information inside `SLF4JLog` class** just like that:

```
2012-12-03 10-30-04 TRACE org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SLF4JLog.trace(104): message
```

It looks like that Grails uses legacy `commons-logging` bridge `jcl-over-slf4j` which might be ok, according to the [SLF4J documentation](http://www.slf4j.org/legacy.html#jclOverSLF4J), and location information should be(?) converted via [`LocationAwareLogger`](http://www.slf4j.org/api/org/slf4j/spi/LocationAwareLogger.html).

How can I configure Grails logging for proper logging location info?

Should I use another log method instead of built-in `log.trace(...)`?

Thanks

Comment: Have you figured this out? I'm having the same problem.

Comment: Unfortunately not, just reported as [GRAILS-9826](http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-9826).

Comment: Ok thanks. I just added a comment there with the results of my digging around.